# Embed video stop on div hide

Tags: html, video, hide, embed

Ok, so I'm currently using the code below, to hide and show a div.
The div contains a video which is embedded direct from an MP4 link, the problem i'm having is when I hide the div, the video continues to play in the background, how do I stop this..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the video tag inside the element you want to hide and `pause` it. If you do not have more than one video this should work (assuming you are using HTML5 video of course):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
      var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'block') {
          var video = e.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
          video.pause();
          e.style.display = 'none';
        } else {
          e.style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
</script>
```